# Allow local DNS traffic (to remote DNS servers) filtered by application/daemon, not simply by port

Tags: linux, networking, dns, firewall, iptables

There are lot of examples on the internet about how to use iptables to allow DNS traffic, but all of them are simply adding a dumb rule like

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:53
```

Which filters the traffic based on which port it is sent to. And yes DNS servers use the port 53, but isn't this very insecure? Wouldn't a malicious application that is trying to get through firewall simply talk to a server on that same port? It is just a UDP port, so using such a rule any data to any server can possibly be sent, if they only use that port.

What is the other proper way to only allow the DNS client to use port to send actual DNS queries? Which application is doing DNS requests on Ubuntu, is it possible to only allow that application/daemon throught the firewall? Or a specific user?

Comment: Are you filtering all other outbound traffic in the same way (only allowing HTTP/HTTPS, etc.)?

Comment: Yes it's filtered by user running the application with -m owner. But isn't DNS handled by a DNS daemon for all other applications? Or is every DNS query performed on the system being performed in the process itself that has ordered it?

Comment: The rule is even more dumb that you think, since DNS uses both UDP and TCP and filtering half of it will create a lot of problems.

Comment: You could accept related traffic but drop udp 53, but the best solution that I can see is defining your DNS server of choice and only allowing that server to communicate with udp port 53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But isn't DNS handled by a DNS daemon for all other applications? Or is every DNS query performed on the system being performed in the process itself that has ordered it?

Both. It varies.

- Traditionally Linux systems do not have a dedicated system resolver. Programs using libc functions will automatically load libnss_dns.so and make the queries within the same process.
- However, glibc *does* have a 'nscd' daemon which acts as a central cache for all nsswitch lookups, including DNS. If this daemon is running, then it loads libnss_dns.so and makes DNS queries for the entire system, and other normal processes don't. (But it's meant to act as a cache – if it's too slow to reply, then programs will fall back to direct queries again.)

  Similarly, some Linux distributions come with 'systemd-resolved', which provides *its own* module libnss_resolve.so – if this is enabled, then all address queries are forwarded to the systemd-resolved daemon. (Unless it fails, in which case the configuration usually falls back to the standard 'dns' module again.)
- Libc only handles "name ↔ address" lookup, but it's important to remember that some programs need more than just, so they *have* to use their internal resolver – they will just read the DNS server addresses from `resolv.conf` but will make and send their own DNS requests, e.g. using libresolv, libunbound, libldns, python-dns, or similar.

  For example, `ssh` wants to query SSHFP records; `postfix/smtp` may want to query TLSA records; Minecraft will want to query SRV records; and any Kerberos-using application will want TXT, SRV, URI records. They must send their own DNS queries, because the system name resolver is insufficient.
- And finally some distributions set up a DNS resolver that actually provides DNS service on 'localhost:53' (commonly Unbound or Dnsmasq). In this case all programs – even those making their own queries – actually only talk to the local resolver at 'localhost', and this resolver is the one which actually talks to the outside world.

In short: If you *really* want to be strict about outbound network access, then set up a **local DNS server** using Unbound/BIND/Knot (whether for the machine or for the entire LAN) and limit access to that DNS server only.